# Как отключить дебаг pymem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymem

При запуске программы получаю в консоль вот это, как отключить "это"?

```
2020-08-26 12:25:10,500 - pymem.process - ERROR - AdjustTokenPrivileges error: 0x00000006
2020-08-28 12:25:10,560 - pymem - DEBUG - Process 6056 is being debugged
```

Comment: Может надо отладить код наконец? А вообще это задаётся соответствующим классом `Logger`'а.